# Paypal payment form that sends client info to my email and does the payment at same time

Tags: php, html, css, paypal

What i'm trying to do here is to ask for the client to write his name, address, post code, etc. in a form, that will take him to the paypal payment(pay now button) and that also sends me the input values inserted.

The reason i ask for those things is because the job implies cleaning the windows, leave a paper with the price, the client goes to the website and pays via paypal, but to confirm his payment, i need the address. The payment confirmation will for between paypal and email is mostly the time sent and value, bc paypal does not give any client info.

I had an idea to only send the email when payment is completed, but it's on paypal so i don't know anything about it.

I have tried, using a script that calls two actions, but only one action takes place. I also tried having the *inputs* on another form, but the button calls both of them with a script, but still only one takes action.

I really need this, it's a must for the website and i just can't fo it, I have been trying so hard to find anything that works, and i did find similar problems but my problem still remained.

HTML:

---

```
<form target="_blank"  action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" >
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@hotmail.com">
    
    <!-- Payment Info -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Window Cleaning">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0.50">
    
    <input name="shipping" type="hidden" value="0.00">
    <input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/Window_Cleaner/menu/payment_confirmation/cancel.html" >

    <!-- Client Data -->
    <!-- Set variables that override the address stored with PayPal. -->
    <div id="divContainer" style="width: 90%;">
        
        <input  name="amount" placeholder="Amount">.50£<br>
        <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
        <input  name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required><br>
        <input  style="width: 72%; padding: 10px; margin: 5px;" name="address" placeholder="Address" required><br>
        <input  name="city" placeholder="City" >
        <input  name="zip" placeholder="Post Code" required><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- Button Pay Now -->
    
    <button class="paypalpaybutton" name="submit" >
        <input  style="width: 70px; height: 18px;" type="image"  src="http://localhost/Window_Cleaner/pictures/paypal/pp.png" border="0" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    </button>
</form >
```

---

PHP:

```
<?php //For paypal Form

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $amount=$_POST["amount"];
        $fname=$_POST["first_name"];
        $lname=$_POST["last_name"];
        $address=$_POST["address"];
        $city=$_POST["city"];
        $zip=$_POST["zip"];
        
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        function sanitize_my_email($field) {
            $field = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if (filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }   
        $to_email = 'example@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Payment of Marco\'s Window Cleaning Service';
        //$message;
        $headers = "From: $fname $lname <example@hotmail.com>";//this email is actually my own, as i dont ask for a email, not needed
        $message = "I'm your client, $fname $lname and I have paid $amount £ for the Window Cleaning service you have provided me with.
        
        Address: $address
        City: $city
        Post Code: $zip
        
    **Always confirm the payment and its value on your own paypal account.
        
        
    Regards, Marco's Window Cleaning";
            
        mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
?>
```

---

CSS:

```
    #divContainer input{
        width: 35%;
        padding: 10px; 
        margin: 6px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 0,1px solid black;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
        
    #divContainer input:active{
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    #divContainer input:focus{
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .paypalpaybutton{
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #3671b0;
        border-radius: 35px;
        width: 370px;
        height: 40px;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .paypalpaybutton:hover{
        background-color: #3c7dc3;
    }
```

Comment: fwiw.. you have in your button, the name tag twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one action can take place at a time.

Which one takes place first, and how it reliably triggers the second action to take place, is a design choice. There are multiple ways to do this, with their own complexities and tradeoffs.

The simplest solution is to create the form that sends you the email, and on the resulting page (or after an ajax/XHR/fetch call that submits the data) have a button so the user can pay. You will get emails for things the user has not paid for yet, and they may or may not follow through with a successful payment, either because they don't click to pay or because their payment is declined.

Having them submit a payment before filling out the form also has disadvantages, since you may receive payments and then not get the information you need.

To not have either of the above disadvantages and keep track of both things in a reliable way you need a server with a database and programming logic, which you need to write.

If you'd rather not write your own, third party tools/plugins may offer an off-the-shelf solution, which you can search for.